# How can I keep the BsDatepicker from the ngx-bootstrap always open?

Tags: datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

I want to realize that the bsdate picker is always open. So it is already open at startup and remains open after a click. In the old version an inline version was provided for it. In the current version I can find no example for it, only I found the switch isOpen,

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" bsDatepicker #dp="bsDatepicker" [(bsValue)]="dts.dt" [bsConfig]="bsConfig" [minDate]="minDate" [maxDate]="maxDate" [isOpen]=true>
```

Or

```
import { BsDatepickerConfig, BsLocaleService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';
public bsConfig: Partial<BsDatepickerConfig>;
this.bsConfig = Object.assign({}, {
        containerClass: 'theme-orange',
        isDisabled: true,
        isOpen: true,
        showWeekNumbers: true
    });
```

But both does not work. Do you have an idea or a howto for me?

Is it possible to get a reference to the date picker in the component and then open it from there. And if so, how?

Thank you very much.

Jens

Comment: You can use `triggers=""` and `[outsideClick]="false"`, get reference to the datepicker and open it in ngOnInit but it will be closed after you select any date, due to current implementation.

Comment: @IlyaSurmay *Please* provide functionality for the Date(range)picker to be used inline.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but some of you might want to know that inline date picker has been implemented in version **3.1.5** of ngx-bootstrap.

Here's the component in the source code

https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/development/src/datepicker/bs-datepicker-inline.component.ts